# Identical Particles in Non Relativistic Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

I have a problem with the following reasoning taken from Messiah which is meant to show that there are intrinsic difficulties in identical particles which are neither bosons nor fermions. Suppose the wavefunction of two identical particles is a linear combination of a symmetrized and antisymmetrized part: then the probability of finding *a* particle at 1 and the other at 2 is the sum of the probability of finding the first one at 1 and the second one at 2 and that of finding the first one at 2 and the second one at 1.

By explicit computation (which can be found in Messiah, "Quantum Mechanics" Volume II but it's straightforward) this probability turns out to be dependent on the coefficients of the linear combination. This is interpreted of course as a paradox, because such coefficients should not influence any physical measurement.

My problem with the reasoning is the following: if the particles are *really* identical, then the two events "first at 1, second at 2" and "first at 2, second at 1" should be regarded as indistinguishable, so that the probability should be not the sum of the probabilities stated above, but the squared modulus of the sum of the *amplitudes*: if one does so, it is easy to see that the result is independent of the coefficients of the combination, thus giving no problem of consistence.

As a matter of fact, I cannot see how a nonrelativistic theory of particles which are not bosong nor fermions could be inconsistent, since, as is stated in nearly every book, it is relativity which forces the spin-statistics connection.

Can anyone help me understand if the above reasoning is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I didn't think about it :)